# I've found an exact copy of a Stack Exchange site answer without giving any credit, is that legal?

Tags: discussion, licensing, copyright

I was searching for answers for one of many daily issues we all normally have and found something quite odd. After finding [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431628/how-to-combine-two-or-more-querysets-in-a-django-view/434755#434755) Stack Overflow, I've stumbled upon [this one](https://ednsquare.com/question/thread/aacabb3b-2ca8-4255-82d7-8f0e35b62356), which is an exact copy of the first one.

Should this be allowed?

I thought about posting on Stack Overflow, but I believe that this matter is about Stack Exchange as a whole.